# Grails delete cascade Tree with an OutOfMemory

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I get an exception when I tried to make a delete cascade :

```
 2015-10-15 13:40:31,823 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR StackTrace  - Full  Stack Trace:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at com.linkedin.grails.profiler.ProfilerFilter.doFilterInternal(ProfilerFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError

I do the following :

```
 TreeNode.executeUpdate("delete TreeNode m")
```

Here is my TreeNode domain class :

class TreeNode  {

```
TreeNode parent;

static hasMany = [children : TreeNode, elementsIndex: TreeNode]
static belongsTo = [parent: TreeNode]

static constraints = {
   name(nullable: true)
   port(nullable: true)
   nodeData(nullable: true)
   parent(nullable: true)
}
```

How can I do the delete cascade ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by making a recursive function which delete element one by one :

```
TreeNode deleteTreeNodeParent(TreeNode n) {
    TreeNode node = n
    if (node != null) {
        TreeNode parent = node.parent
        if (parent != null) {
            deleteTreeNodeParent(parent)
        } else {
            node.delete()
        }
    }

}
```

I also deleted the following line in TreeNode class :

```
static belongsTo = [parent: TreeNode]
```